# How to run two activities in different processes

Tags: java, android, multiprocessing

I have two activities in the **same application**, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`.

How do I run each Activity in a different process? I am thinking that I should start a service for each Activity. Is there a better way?

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        ....
        startActivity(intent1);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }
}
```

I am not interested in different threads. I want different processes.

Comment: @PacoAbato I am not using AsyncTask. I don't want threads I want processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your manifest,set the activities to run on different processes as in my below example

```
         <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:name=".ui.MapsActivity"
            android:process=":MapView"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:name=".ui.MapsActivity02"
            android:process=":MapView02"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
       </activity>
```

Comment: In your example how do I specify `:MapView02`? What is that?

Comment: This is just the name of the process(just give any name),declaring two different process names sets the activity to run on different process.But always include the colon before the name

Comment: If I do thisa I am not able to maintain values of static variable.can u pls help me througt this?

Comment: each process has it's own memory share.